# Windows 10 Boot Linux without BIOS menu or USB stick

Tags: linux, windows

I have Linux both command line linux, and Ubuntu, but my computer is Windows 10 based. Also the hardware is not what it used to be. I.e... No working USB port, No DVD slot (But I do have a Micro SD slot if I can boot it from there) but I was wondering if I can install and boot linux directly in Windows? And I was wondering if Windows 10 would be active still, and if I an switch in between the two? I have never worked with Linux or booted it. How can I boot linux in windows without anything but a micro sd card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not boot linux on windows. you can make Bootable USB and use live linux or use virtual machine like [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/)

Comment: Bootable USB is not available, but can I boot it from a Micro SD card? None of the storage hardware works except for the Micro SD slot.

Comment: @IgnatiusReborn2.0 use https://unetbootin.github.io/ and treat it as a USB stick.

Comment: I see... so say Windows (Original OS on my computer) stops working... will it effect my Linux OS? How do I boot it?

Comment: no it won't. just follow instructions in https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: Is there a danger in the process? Also could I possibly run android as well on this computer? Or just Desktop like Linux, Windows and Mac?

Comment: Not working with my Micro SD card

Comment: you can run android use http://www.bluestacks.com/

Comment: can you give me details why it's not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual machine. They allow you to run multiple operating systems at once, and as long as your machine supports virtualization, they work perfectly for the situation you are describing.

My preferred virtualization software include:

[VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/)

and

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox)

From there, download and install the Linux .iso file of your choice to be able to open and switch between operating systems at will. Also, make sure to enable virtualization in your BIOS settings.

Comment: VirtualBox no longer works in the latest version of Windows 10

Comment: VMWare never worked on Windows 10. So I wish to boot it direct, so if Windows stops working, then I have a backup OS

Comment: Actually, VMWare and VirtualBox both work on Windows 10. I know, I am running both of them right now.

Comment: Make sure to enable virtualization such as VT-X in your computer's BIOS if x64 isos will not boot for you.

Comment: It does not work with mine... It never starts at all. But I will give it a try I guess... If Windows breaks... Will it shut down Linux too? Cause Windows 10 instability on my computer is kinda the reason I want to explore another OS too and have one for backup.

Comment: I only have 32bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, if Windows is unstable, getting a virtual machine is not going to help at all. It runs one operating system on top of the other, not side by side. You would need to dual boot to install it separately, and that usually requires external media which you do not have.

Comment: Thats why I want to have multiple OS's and not a virtual machine.

Comment: You won't be able to swap between them without a reboot, though.

Comment: Dual Boot, which I am gonna use that program the other answer suggested to treat micro sd as a USB, do I boot it from BIOS or directly in windows for it to be dual boot?

Comment: I dont mind as long as it does not flash my computer if I must do it from                BIOS